# Cannot Access Data in Serialized JSON Object Flutter

Tags: json, serialization, flutter, dart

I am trying to serialize JSON data into an manual created Object. Whenever I try to access the data, I get a null but, if I print the length of the serialized data, I am told that I have 8 items in my array. I'm currently using   json_annotation: ^2.0.0 and json_serializable: as dependancies in my project.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

My object:

```
class Restaurant {
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;
  String city;
  String restaurantPhoto;
  String state;
  double lat;
  double long;
  String rating;

  Restaurant({
    this.id,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.restaurantPhoto,
    this.lat,
    this.long,
    this.name,
    this.state,
    this.rating,
  });

  factory RestaurantPhoto.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json){
     return Restaurant(
    id: json['id'] as int,
    name: json[‘restaurant_name'] as String,
    address: json['street_address'] as String,
    city: json['city'] as String,
    restaurantPhoto: json['restaurant_photo'] as String,
    state: json['state'] as String,
    lat: json['lat'] as double,
    long: json['lng'] as double,
    rating: json['rating'] as String,
  );
  }
}
```

Here is my method:

```
  Future getRestaurants() async {
  var url = 'http://restaurant-8821.herokuapp.com/api/customer/restaurant/';

  http.get(url, headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }).then((http.Response response) {
    // print(response.body);

    Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);

    Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant.fromJSON(responseData);
    print(responseData);
    print(restaurant.name);

    print(restaurant().length);

  });
}
```

From the method three items will be printed and the responseData prints:

```
{restaurant: [{id: 4, restaurant_name: The Oasis, phone: 123-123-1234, street_address: 456 Fake St, restaurant_logo: https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/restaurantLogo_jXon4qm.jpg, restaurant_photo: https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/farmas.jpg, city: New York, state: New York, zip_Code: 12345, lat: 40.0, lng: 40.0, latlng: (40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265), opening_hours: [], ratings: 3.0},
```

Restaurant name comes up null and restaurant.string.length prints out 12.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have mistyped backquote instead of quote letter

```
 name: json[‘restaurant_name'] as String,
```

try this

```
name: json['restaurant_name'] as String,
```

Comment: I made the change but, I still cannot access the data.

Comment: Yes. I print out the response body no problem. It's then i try to access decode the json data in the api call to the object: Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant.fromJSON(responseData). I dont know how to get responseData into the object and use it. It give me a null